# Is there any algorithm for covering a concave polygon(contains holes) with convex polygons

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, polygons

This can be approached in two ways :

i)  by partitioning the given polygon into convex polygons such that there is no 
    overlap between the convex polygons

ii) by covering the given polygon using convex polygons such that their union 
    gives the original polygon. In this case there can be overlap between 
    the convex polygons

Although partitioning covers the entire polygon, number of convex polygons can be reduced by second approach. It is also known that covering a concave polygon(second approach) with minimal number of convex polygons is NP-Hard.

I'm specifically looking for algorithms based on second approach mentioned above,but number of convex polygons may not be minimal.

Comment: No, It should cover the given polygon not more than that!!

Comment: You are looking for `polygon decomposition` into convex parts. The simplest methods  - `polygon triangulation` and `trapezoidal decomposition`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm looking for algorithms other than triangulation since  it gives me many convex polygons

Comment: @KvsnRaju: it is easy to find cases that require a linear number of polygons (which makes both triangulation and trapezoidal decomposition asymptotically optimal in the worst case). So you should be more specific about an acceptable number.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by MBo and Yves Daoust in the comments to your questions. Polygon decomposition into convex polygons can be done by triangulation (or trapezoidal decomposition). This will result for an n vertex simple polygon P with n-2 (interior) triangles, i.e., is linear in the number of vertices.

Another way to construct a convex decomposition would be to use a generalized [motorcycle graph](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/open/cycles.html). I would assume there must be a simpler way though! 
The main idea is to start a motorcycle m for every reflex vertex r in P. Every motorcycle m drives with a given speed in a given direction and leaves a trace behind. If another motorcycle meets such a trace it crashes, i.e., stops but leaves the trace. 
Generalized refers to the embedding in P and that the polygon boundaries function as walls where the motorcycles also crash. Furthermore if two motorcycles meet at the same point we have to start another one, or in this case just continue with one and stop the other. After all motorcycles have crashed there is the graph of the traces which in fact is a convex tessellation of P. There are several papers ([one here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-014-9625-2)) on this but implementation would be tough. This results in O(r) convex polygons that cover the interior of P.

I think the easiest way is to go with the triangulation or trapezoidal decomposition. These are well studied and available as implementation in many libraries.

Also mentioned in the comments: Input can be produced that will force O(n) polygons. Just think of a star shaped polygon that has n/2 reflex vertices (interior angle > pi).